# What is Malware Family: pva.intowow

Tags: malware

I've gotten an e-mail from my ISP saying that one of my devices might be infected with malware.

In the e-mail they have provided me with some information about the malware but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Details sent in the e-mail

```
IP [An IP owned by my ISP] .
 data: SOURCE TIME: 2021-07-24 05:13:29Z
IP: [An IP owned by my ISP]
ASN: [3 digit number]
AS NAME: [My ISP]
MALWARE FAMILY: pva.intowow
TYPE: botnet drone
DESCRIPTION: This host is most likely infected with malware.
DESTINATION IP: [An Ip owned by a 3rd party website]
DESTINATION PORT: 80
PORT: 40546
HTTP REQUEST: /api/1/tracking
UUID
: [Some GUID]
```

I can understand `botnet drone` but other than [a page with statistics taken from "a database containing infected systems in Switzerland"](https://www.govcert.admin.ch/statistics/malware/) I and everyone I've talked to at my ISPs technical support have no idea what `MALWARE FAMILY: pva.intowow` means.

I'm hoping that by understanding what `pva.intowow` means I'll be better able to hunt down which device is infected and remove the malware.

Comment: Is this you? https://telekomhilft.telekom.de/t5/Telefonie-Internet/pva-intowow/td-p/5273216

Comment: No that is not me.

Comment: Then you aren't the only confused person out there on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a 20-year security professional, I can't think of a more unhelpful email to send to customers. It might as well say: "Look! We found a virus on the Internet!"

Knowing the malware family will do nothing to help you find the device on your network. [Intowow](https://www.intowow.com/) is an ad provider and consumer tracker, and this makes sense with the HTTP request of `/api/1/tracking`. You would have to ask the ISP what their malware detector means by the designation `pva`. But, as I said, it's likely not going to be useful.

If possible, you could look at your router to find connections out to that IP on port 80 from an IP inside your network. But few home routers log at that level, or for long.

You could also set up logs on your PCs looking for connections out on port 80 in hopes of catching a connection, but that will be tedious.

Comment: Good chance the ISP just received this message from a third party and is relaying it without having any more details on what is actually reported. Not reporting often isn't that much of an option, because you'd be withholding possibly relevant information about the customers' security.

Comment: Reporting to users? Sure. But that detail list is anti-helpful. A general description and "next steps" would be helpful. That email isn't even useful for a security pro.

Comment: I totally agree on that, but it’s something I see every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I think PVA stands for Potentially Vulnerable Application (PVA), also known as Potentially Unwanted Applications (PUA).

Microsoft suggests some of these next steps:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/protect-your-pc-from-potentially-unwanted-applications-c7668a25-174e-3b78-0191-faf0607f7a6e

Comment: I can find no reference to "Potentially Vulnerable Application (PVA)" anywhere. Do you have any reference to back up your assertion? That would be an odd class of software since *all* applications are "potentially vulnerable". Plus, Intowow doesn't offer an app to consumers. there would not be an Intowow app, unwanted or otherwise...